# Inject ID into component: Difference between custom component and "primitive" (<div />) component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to write a component that injects an ID into it's child component. Something like:

```
<Id id='someId'>
    <div>Hello!</div>
</Id>
```

With an expected output of: `<div id='someId'>Hello!</div>`

---

I have it working whenever I use standard HTML components like `<div />`, `<span />`, etc. I can't, however, get it to work whenever I use a custom component.

```
const Foo = ({ children }) => (
    <span>{children}</span>
)

<Id id='someId'><Foo>Child of Foo</Foo></Id>
```

The above will not work and I'm not sure why. Here's what the `<Id />` component looks like:

```
import * as React from 'react'

export const Id = ({ children, id }) => (
    React.cloneElement(children, { id })
)

export default Id
```

---

**UPDATE**: Answer is I can't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing `React.cloneElement(children, { id });`, you are actually creating a react component and pass props into it. In this case `{ id }` is the same as `{ id: id }`, which mean you are passing the value of the variable `id` as a props named `id` to `Foo`. You can access the value in `Foo` from `this.props.id`.

You should retrieve the `id` passed as props in `Foo`, then pass it as to the `span`.

```
const Foo = ({ children, id }) => (
    <span id={id}>{children}</span>
);
```

About what you asked in the comment, you can achieve it by telling `Foo` to pass all props, no matter what it is. Something like:

```
const Foo = props => {
   return <span {...props}>{props.children}</span>;
};
```

Check this updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o4k62qom09).

I don't think there is any other way for you to achieve it if you don't want the component to be aware that it needs to handle `id`. AFAIK, most npm packages that works with HOC need to be aware about what are the names of the `props` that need to be handled.

Comment: Follow up question then: How would I go if I wanted a HoC that injects the ID to a child component. I'm doing this component because I *don't* want the child component to be aware it needs to handle the ID. Doing like you're suggesting would defeat the purpose.

Comment: I see, so I probably need to revisit the structure and reevaluate the needs then... Thank you for the answer.